# How to keep assembly files when using scons？

Tags: scons

When I use a command like `env.Program('hello','spectre_full.c')` in Sconstruct, it generates the `spectre_full.o` file and the `hello` executable file.

1. But I want to know its assembly code, how should I set it to keep the assembly code.
2. And what is the use of this .o file? Is this .o file used to determine whether the two generations have changed?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the compiler itself will internally generate the assembly code and use that to build the .o.

Pretty much any compiler when presented with a .c to generate an executable will generate an intermediate .o for all .c files presented.

SCons knows that a Program requires .o's so effectively does this:

```
env.Program('hello',env.Object('spectre_full.c'))
```

Depending on your specific compiler, there may be a command line flag to get it to generate and not remove the assembler file.
Once you figure that out you can add it to your SConstruct via

```
env.Append('CFLAGS','-whatever your flag is')
```

or

```
env.Program('hello','spectre_full.c', CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -whatever your flag is")
```